# Porting codepen website over to github pages - collapsed nav button not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have recently tried to port a website I made in codepen over to GitHub pages. I've been having issues with the site as the collapsed navbar button doesn't appear to work with the new site. The page is responsive etc but the button does nothing when clicked. Would appreciate some help.
[Site](http://15jacobj.github.io)

Don't know what section of code you want but here's a little of what you might need.

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Jacob Jones- portfolio</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css"/>



<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
  <body>

 <!-- Navbar start -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-custom" id="bar">
 <div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="btn btn-default" class="navbar-toggle collapsed btn btn-default collps" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="true">
    <span class="sr-only"></span>


   <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>

  </button>

</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class><a href="#about-me">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#skill-set">Skillset</a></li>

     <li><a href="#projects">Portfolio</a></li>

  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to link both the **JavaScript** code for Bootstrap, as well as the **jQuery** library (which Bootstrap's JavaScript's depends on). To resolve this, add the following two lines to your `<head>` (ensuring you load the jQuery library **before** Bootstrap's JavaScript):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Note** that if you run your site over HTTPS, you may get mixed content warnings. As such, you'll need to use a protocol-agnostic source:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This will fix the menu functionality, as is demonstrated below (minus your custom CSS):

```html
<head>
  <title> Jacob Jones- portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navbar start -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom" id="bar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="btn btn-default" class="navbar-toggle collapsed btn btn-default collps" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="true">
          <span class="sr-only"></span>
          <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class><a href="#about-me">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#skill-set">Skillset</a></li>
          <li><a href="#projects">Portfolio</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Still doesn't work :( Have u tried to see the site for youself so we can deny/confirm the problem?

Comment: Ok. Solved now - you were right-ish but turns out you need to have the tage for jquery and bootstrap just above body tag for them to work. Thanks for quick reponse and problem solved.

Comment: My apologies; I didn't initially realise you were running over HTTPS, and the links I gave were HTTP. You need to use protocol-agnostic links for HTTPS: `//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com...`. I've updated my code to correct this, and I'm glad to hear you got it working :)